# Why does setting use-package-always-ensure cause Emacs to contact package repositories at startup?

Tags: use-package, package-repositories, start-up

I have the following in my init.el:

```
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)
```

because I want packages referenced by `use-package` to be downloaded automatically if I don't have them.

When I enable this setting however, *every time* Emacs starts I see "Contacting host ..." for each package repository (ELPA, MELPA, etc) before start-up is complete and it takes a very long time. It's as if my package archive contents are always assumed to be stale.

Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

Answer (score 1):

After a quick skim of the `org-package-ensure` package’s source code, it should only contact the package server if it is asked to install a package that you don’t have. Are you sure you’re not asking it to install a package that doesn’t exist?